# Django Update Existing ImageField not working

Tags: django, image, django-models, imagefield

I want to give a user the ability to update the image associated to a record.
I have an edit form that allows the user to update various elements of a record all of which are updating correctly except for the image fields.
The image field when assigned to the record is displaying so adding the image to the record on creation fo the record works fine.
I have reviewed similar Q&As and they have not helped.

**Models.py**

```
class ComicInput(models.Model):
        CoverPic = models.ImageField(upload_to='Comic_Pics', default='Comic_Pics/default.png',blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % ( self.CoverPic)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s %s %s' % ( self.CoverPic)
```

**Forms.py**

```
 class ComicInputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ComicInput
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.Py**

```
def edit(request, id):
   record = ComicInput.objects.get(pk = id)
   return render(request, 'app/edit.html',{"ComicInput":record})

def update(request, id):
   updaterecord = ComicInput.objects.get(pk = id)
   if request.method == "POST":
    form = editform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=updaterecord)
    if form.is_valid():
        edit = form.save(commit=False)
        edit.save()
        return ComicInventory(request)
    else :
        form = editform(instance=updaterecord)
        messages.error(request,"Error, please try again taking note of validation rules on the right")
        return render(request, 'app/edit.html', {'form':form,"ComicInput":updaterecord})

def delete(request, id):
   deleterecord = ComicInput.objects.get(pk = id)
   deleterecord.delete()
   return ComicInventory(request)
```

**Urls.py**

```
path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit, name='edit'),
path('update/<int:id>', views.update, name='update'),
path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

**Template - edit.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Update Collection Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Update your Comic</h1>
    <h4>Values for inputs that contain validation are noted on the right</h4>
        {%if messages%}
            {%for updaterecord in messages%}
            <h3 style="color: green; float:">{{updaterecord}}</h3> 
            {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="/update/{{ComicInput.id}}" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Input</th>
                        <th scope="col">Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" value="{{ComicInput.id}}" readonly /></td>
                    <td>Read Only</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>CoverPic</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="CoverPic" value="{{ComicInput.CoverPic}}" /></td>
                    <td>Must be a file path URL</td>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Update"/> | <a href="{% url 'ComicInventory' %}"> View Collection</a>
        
        
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

**NEW HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Update Collection Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Update your Comic</h1>
    <h4>Values for inputs that contain validation are noted on the right</h4>
        {%if messages%}
            {%for updaterecord in messages%}
            <h3 style="color: green; float:none">{{updaterecord}}</h3> 
            {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="/update/{{ComicInput.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table table-striped">


             <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Field Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Current Value</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit Values</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="id" value="{{ComicInput.id}}" readonly /></td>
                    <td>Read Only</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Publisher</td>
                    <<td>"{{ComicInput.Publisher}}"</td>
                    <td>{{ form.Publisher}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>BackPic</td>
                    <td>{{form.BackPic}}</td>
                    <td> Current path: "{{ComicInput.BackPic}}" Must be a file path URL</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>CoverPic</td>
                    <td>{{ form.CoverPic}}</td>
                    <td> Current path: "{{ComicInput.CoverPic}}" Must be a file path URL</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>ContentPic</td>
                    <td>{{ form.ContentPic}}</td>
                    <td> Current path: "{{ComicInput.ContentPic}}" Must be a file path URL</td>

            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Update"/> | <a href="{% url 'ComicInventory' %}"> View Collection</a>
    

    
    
    </form>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: How come you're rendering out the form markup yourself and not using the form created by django? For example `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: The Model Form input validation wasn't working when I did that for some reason so then I added another table column to describe the input validation (there are a dozen inputs on this form). Plus I wanted to see the id for now and make it read only.

Comment: @markwalker_ thanks for the edit

Comment: did you get working yet?

Comment: If a change the html to use the django markup with {{form}}, it no longer displays the current record data but the  image field is editable - I would like to see the current record data and update the imagefiled - so perhaps my issue is really rendering the form with the current record. new HTML above.

Comment: For now I can use a workaround where I render the existing value in html as text and I render the Django form besides it for editing. This will be a sufficient work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit View**

```
def edit(request, id):
   record = ComicInput.objects.get(pk = id)
   form = editform(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=record)
   return render(request, 'app/edit.html',{'form':form,"ComicInput":record})

**HTML**

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Update Collection Record</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Update your Comic</h1>
    <h4>Values for inputs that contain validation are noted on the right</h4>
        {%if messages%}
            {%for updaterecord in messages%}
            <h3 style="color: green; float:none">{{updaterecord}}</h3> 
            {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST" action="/update/{{ComicInput.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table class="table table-striped">


             <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Field Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Current Value</th>
                        <th scope="col">Edit Values</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  {{form}}
            </table>
    
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: So I saw I removed the record instance from the edit view which prevented the record values coming in- so I've placed the instance back in the view. using django to render the form in the html template works well now - thanks @markwalker_